# Symfony 3.1.4 form login causes apache Segmentation Fault

Tags: apache, segmentation-fault, symfony

With my Symfony 3.1.4 application i got a segmentation fault under apache. 
What i am trying to do is just to perform a simple login action like its been shown here:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html

As soon as i submit the login form the server quits the connection with a segmentation fault (11) in the apache logs:

**My Configs**

PHP: 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3
Apache: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
OS: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

**Enabled Apache Modules**

Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 watchdog_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 log_config_module (static)
 logio_module (static)
 version_module (static)
 unixd_module (static)
 access_compat_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 filter_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 mpm_prefork_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 php7_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)

**Enabled PHP Modules**
[PHP Modules]
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
sockets
SPL
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlrpc
xmlwriter
xsl
zlib

[Zend Modules]

**Security Controller:**

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationUtils;

class SecurityController extends Controller
{
/**
 * @var AuthenticationUtils
 */
protected $authenticationUtils;

public function __construct(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils)
{
    $this->authenticationUtils = $authenticationUtils;
}

public function loginAction(Request $request)
{
    $error = $this->authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
    $lastUsername = $this->authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

    return $this->render('security/login.html.twig', [
        'last_username' => $lastUsername,
        'error' => $error
    ]);
}
}
```

**Twig Template**

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

 {% block body %}

<div class="section custombg nopadding page-title-wrapper">
     <div class="container">
        <div class="row clearfix">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                 <div class="title-area pull-left">
                    <h2>Anmeldung</h2>
                </div><!-- /.pull-right -->
            </div><!-- end col -->
        </div><!-- end page-title -->
    </div><!-- end container -->
</div>

<div class="section min-height">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row page-wrapper">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                <div class="widget clearfix">
                    <div class="widget-title withbg">
                        <h3>Ich habe bereits einen Account</h3>
                     </div><!-- end widget-title -->

                    <p>
                        Bitte logge dich hier mit deinen Zugangsdaten ein.
                    </p>

                    <div class="form-wrapper">

                        {% if error %}
                            {{ app.request.locale }}
                            <div>{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</div>
                       {% endif %}

                    <form action="{{ path('login') }}" method="post">
                        <label for="username">Benutzername:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" />

                        <label for="password">Passwort:</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="_password" />

                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-flat">Anmelden</button>
                    </form>
                </div><!-- end form-container -->
            </div><!-- end clearfix -->
        </div><!-- end col -->
    </div><!-- end row -->
</div><!-- end container -->
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

i've also tried to restart apache and mysql server, but it doesnt helped out. anyone having an idea?

GDB Backtrace full:

```
#0  0x00007fd5bee7f64a in __GI___waitpid (pid=-1,    stat_loc=0x7ffc479365a0, options=10) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/waitpid.c:29
    resultvar = 18446744073709551104
#1  0x0000000000446fbd in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#2  0x000000000044849b in wait_for ()
No symbol table info available.
#3  0x000000000043842f in execute_command_internal ()
 No symbol table info available.
#4  0x000000000043848e in execute_command ()
No symbol table info available.
#5  0x000000000042139e in reader_loop ()
No symbol table info available.
#6  0x000000000041fdb1 in main ()
No symbol table info available.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is fixed:

The error was caused by a never ending recursive call in a php function of mine. in PHP 7.0.8 this was causing the apache to crash and shutdown. in 7.0.11 i was getting the error message and was able to fix this error. So php 7.0.8 seems to be a little buggy.